# How to replace two slash into one slash?

Tags: c#, .net

We have the following code:

```
string str="\\u5b89\u5fbd\\";
```

We need output in the format:

```
"\u5b89\u5fbd\"
```

We have tried this code:

```
str.Replace("\\",@"\")
```

Its not working.

Comment: *"Its not working"* What happens instead?

Comment: `str.Replace("\\",@"\")` is same `str.Replace(@"\",@"\")`. May be you need `str.Replace(@"\\",@"\")`

Comment: Should `string str="\\u5b89\u5fbd\\";` read `string str="\\u5b89\\u5fbd\\";` instead?

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
string str = "\\u5b89\u5fbd\\";
str = str.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

`\`  is a reserved sign. `\\` escapes it and results in `\`
Adding `@` at the start of a string tell the compiler to use the string as is and not to escape characters.

So use either `"\\\\"`  or `@"\\"`

### EDIT

`\\u5b89\u5fbd\\` actually does not have two `\` together. `\` is just escaped. 
The string results in `\u5b89徽\`. And in that string you can't replace `\\` because there is only one `\` together.

Comment: "\\u5b89\u5fbd\\" is actually \u5b89徽\. So the is no \\ in it.

Comment: @PrateekSaluja: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: string str = "\\u5b89\u5fbd\\"; Output should be  "\u5b89\u5fbd\";

Comment: @PrateekSaluja: But that output doesn't even compile! Where do you get the input from?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
str.Replace("\\\\","\\");
```

Your example accomplish nothing. `"\\"` is an escaped version of `\`, and `@"\"` is another version of writing `\`. So your example replaces `\` with `\`

**EDIT**
Now I understand your problem. What you want can't actually be done, since that would cause the string to end with a single \, and that will not be allowed. \ denotes a start of a escape sequence, and needs something after it.

I think there are no good option here, since in your case \u5b89 is not a string, but an escape sequence for one specific character.

```
str.Replace("\\u5b89","\u5b89");
```

This works for your current example, but will only work with this one specific character, so I guess it wont help you much. The \ at the end you cannot replace with \, but I can't see why you need the string to end with this char either.

Your best bet is to make sure that the \ does not occur at the start of the string in the first place, instead of trying to get rid of it afterwards.

Comment: Your example replaces \\ with \, but the original string doesn't contain \\, it only contains \, so your example also accomplishes nothing.

Comment: Its run time data so we don't know the string so problem will remain.

Comment: But regardless, your problem remains. From \u5b89 you can't extract \ or u or 5 or b89, or any other subpart, since it is actually just a single character, and not 6 characters

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the first string is actually saved as:

```
"\u5b89[someChineseCharacter]\"
```

because you are already using escape sequences. If you would like the original string to be what you typed, you have to do it like so:

```
string str = @"\\u5b89\u5fbd\\";
```

Then, `str = str.Replace(@"\\",@"\")` would work.

### Some clarification:

When you type `string str="\\u5b89\u5fbd\\";` in visual studio, it saves the string `\u5b89徽\` in memory, because you are using several escape sequences in the original statement:

`\\` actually means `\`

`\u5fbd` actually means unicode character 5fbd, which is `徽`.

For that reason, these get replaced, and in memory your string looks as mentioned.

So if you try to replace occurrences of two backslashes `@"\\"`, it will appear to do nothing, because there were no such occurrences in the original string to begin with.

Hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will solve your problem.

> str.Replace("\\\\","\\");

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe Something like this?

```
foreach (char c in str)
{
    if ((int)c < 256)
        Console.Write(c);
    else
        Console.Write(String.Format("\\u{0:x4}", (int)c));
}
```

;)

Comment: Assign this values to variable you will get same output.

Comment: I don't understand, is that a good or bad thing? In the code above, if str = "\\u5b89\u5fbd\\" the output will be \u5b89\u5fbd\

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is just me but I think the input string should have a "\" in the middle, or the second `u5fbd` will be interpreted as a unicode char (so you won't get it outputted as you wish). With a starting string like this:

```
string str="\\u5b89\\u5fbd\\";
```

You don't need any replace to output what you want, if for "output" you mean something like Console or an HTML page...